# How to parse a .shp file?

Tags: python, parsing, arcgis, shapefile

I am interested in gleaning information from an ESRI `.shp` file.
Specifically the `.shp` file of a polyline feature class.

When I open the `.dbf` of a feature class, I get what I would expect: a table that can open in excel and contains the information from the feature class' table.

However, when I try to open a `.shp` file in any program (excel, textpad, etc...) all I get is a bunch of gibberish and unusual ASCII characters.

I would like to use Python (2.x) to interpret this file and get information out of it (in this case the vertices of the polyline).

I do not want to use any modules or non built-in tools, as I am genuinely interested in how this process would work and I don't want any dependencies.

Thank you for any hints or points in the right direction you can give!

Comment: I think the best hint I could give would be to solve a more interesting problem.  Once you understand how to read binary files and use the `struct` module and so on, all that's left is the timesink of actually doing it, and there's not much point except for pedagogical reasons.

Comment: Sorry, it's just how I think!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question, basically, is "I have a file full of data stored in an arbitrary binary format. How can I use python to read such a file?"

The answer is, [this link](http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf) contains a description of the format of the file. Write a dissector based on the technical specification.

Comment: I think you are probably right. I printed out that paper a few days ago and am trying to decipher it.

Comment: Oh, and for extra fun, this format explicitly uses both big-endian and little-endian byte ordering if different sections.

Comment: It's seems fairly straightforward... Start with a 100-byte header that contains a magic number, bounding box information, and shape type (one type of shape per file), followed by records. Each record has an 8-byte header, specifying record number and record size (in 2-byte words), and ooh, each record is a serialization of a complex data structure, I see. And the rest of the file explains the data structures and how they are pickled. So you'll need a separate unpickle function for each type of shape...

Comment: Data stored in byte form has no spaces or syntax or anything right? if it says a header is 100 bytes, that LITERALLY means 800 ones or zeros and then that header is over, no more no less?
So I should be able to just parse past a give number of bytes to get to the bytes I want if I am understanding this correctly.

Comment: Yes, literally a hundred bytes. On the other hand, the size of each shape record is variable, so if you're trying to get the third shape, you have to seek past the file header, extract the size from the first record header to find the second, and extract the size from the second header to find the third. (And don't forget to multiple the size by two to get the bytecount of the record, and don't forget that the size doesn't include the record header (8 bytes), and don't forget that you'll need big/little_endian_to_host_order conversion functions to read numbers in headers and records...

Comment: Well it took all this time, but I finally figured it out! Thanks for the helpful tips in the right direction. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to go to all the trouble of writing a parser, you should take look at [pyshp](https://code.google.com/p/pyshp/), a pure Python shapefile library. I've been using it for a couple of months now, and have found it quite easy to use.

There's also a python binding to shapelib, if you search the web. But I found the pure Python solution easier to hack around with.

Answer (score 0):

might be a long shot, but you should check out ctypes, and maybe use the .dll file that came with a program (if it even exists lol) that can read that type of file. in my experience, things get weird when u start digging around .dlls